# primefaces breadcrumb not working with ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am not able to render the **breadcrumb** control of primefaces. I am dynamically building the breadcrumb using ui:repeat. The moment I wrapped it inside the **p:breadCrumb** tag , I am not able to see the control on the page

Following code I am using in my .xhtml

```
        <p:breadCrumb>
        <ui:repeat value="#{conversationScope.trail}" var="bcrumb">
            <h:outputLink value="#{bcrumb.url}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bcrumb.label}" />
                <h:outputText value=">" />
            </h:outputLink>
            <p:menuitem value="#{bcrumb.label}" url="#{bcrumb.url}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:breadCrumb>
```

Please suggest is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build a `<p:breadCrumb>` menu in PrimeFaces dynamically you'll want to use a MenuModel object in your bean for the breadCrumb component to render. Loop through your trail list creating MenuItems and add them the MenuModel object.

In your .xhtml

```
<p:breadCrumb model="#{crumbBean.model}" />
```

Bean to add menu items to the breadcrumb menu.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultMenuModel;
import org.primefaces.model.MenuModel;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CrumbBean {

    private MenuModel model;

    public CrumbBean() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
        item1.setValue("First");
        item1.setUrl("#");
        model.addMenuItem(item1);

        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
        item2.setValue("Second");
        item2.setUrl("#");
        model.addMenuItem(item2);
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```